# Django displays source code instead of web page

Tags: html, django, web, django-views

I am new to django. Any help will be appreciated. It displays source code instead of web page. To be specific the base page (base.html). What I want is to use the data from patient details and doctors detail as they are from different groups. I think that the problem is when i pass my dictionary.

Views.py

```py
def booking(request):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        messages.success(
            request, ("In order to book an appointment you must login first"))
        return redirect('login')
    doctor_details = Doctor.objects.all()
    f = {'doctor_details': doctor_details}
    g = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
    if g == 'Patient':
        patient_details = Patient.objects.all().filter(EmailAddress=request.user)
        d = {'patient_details': patient_details}
    return render(request, 'booking.html', f, d)
```

Html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}


<div class="loginContainer">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="{% static 'image/booking.svg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="login-content">
        {% for d in patient_details %}
        <form method="POST" id="signupForm">
            {% for f in doctors_details %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="title">Booking form</h2>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Patient ID: PID - {{d.id}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Name: {{d.FirstName}} {{d.LastName}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="business"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Department</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="age" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="medkit"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>{{f.name}}</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="age" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="bandage"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Symptoms</h5>
                    <input type="textarea" class="input" name="address" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="document-text"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Comments (Optional)</h5>
                    <input type="textarea" class="input" name="address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="loginBtn">Submit</button>
            <a href="userProfile" class="section-btn btn btn-default btn-blue smoothScroll">Return to Personal Profile</a>
            <a href="./" class="section-btn btn btn-default btn-blue smoothScroll">Cancel Booking</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% ifequal error 'no' %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You have successfully registered.")
    window.location = ('loginPage')
</script>
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal error 'yes' %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Something went wrong.")
</script>
{% endifequal %}
{% endblock %}
```

Urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('contact', views.contact),
    path('loginPage', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('doctorlogin', views.doctorlogin, name='doclogin'),
    path('help', views.help),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('doctors', views.doctors, name='doctors'),
    path('booking', views.booking, name='booking'),
    path('userProfile', views.userProfile, name='userProfile'),
    path('doctorProfile', views.doctorProfile, name='doctorProfile'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + \
    static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: did you run ```python manage.py runserver``` in the terminal?

Comment: Please share content of `urls.py` and `views.py` files. Django template skips those values that are missing when rendering the page, so it doesn't seem like an error with just the way you pass this dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass context as one dictionary. You can use `update` method to add new items to your dictionary:

```py
def booking(request):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        messages.success(
            request, ("In order to book an appointment you must login first"))
        return redirect('login')
    doctor_details = Doctor.objects.all()
    f = {'doctor_details': doctor_details}
    g = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
    if g == 'Patient':
        patient_details = Patient.objects.all().filter(EmailAddress=request.user)
        f.update({'patient_details': patient_details}) # Using update
    return render(request, 'booking.html', f)
```

Comment: Thanks. What should i do in html part??

Comment: @DarshanBuddhacharya I'm not sure but I think the html is fine. But it's better to use `doctors_details` out of `patient_details` form if they are not related.

Comment: Nope, It now shows the webpage but the form disappear

Comment: @DarshanBuddhacharya You should have at least one Doctor and Patient in the dictionary for the form to display.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for contributing. I found my mistake. The problem was in the way i use the views.py. The above answer is correct but i prefer to use it this way.
Views.py

```
def booking(request):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        messages.success(
            request, ("In order to book an appointment you must login first"))
        return redirect('login')
    doctor_details = Doctor.objects.all()
    g = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
    if g == 'Patient':
        patient_details = Patient.objects.all().filter(EmailAddress=request.user)
        d = {'patient_details': patient_details,
             'doctor_details': doctor_details} #edited part
    return render(request, 'booking.html', d)
```

And for the html part.
Html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}


<div class="loginContainer">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="{% static 'image/booking.svg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="login-content">
        <form method="POST" id="signupForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="title">Booking form</h2>
            {% for f in patient_details%} #here is the change
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Patient ID: PID - {{f.id}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Name: {{f.FirstName}} {{f.LastName}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
                {% endfor %}
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="business"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Department</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="age" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="medkit"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <div class="custom-select">
                        <select name="doctors" required>
                            {% for f in doctor_details %} #here is the change
                                <option value="{{f.name}}">{{f.name}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="bandage"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Symptoms</h5>
                    <input type="textarea" class="input" name="address" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <ion-icon name="document-text"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Comments (Optional)</h5>
                    <input type="textarea" class="input" name="address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="loginBtn">Submit</button>
            <a href="userProfile" class="section-btn btn btn-default btn-blue smoothScroll">Return to Personal Profile</a>
            <a href="./" class="section-btn btn btn-default btn-blue smoothScroll">Cancel Booking</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% ifequal error 'no' %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You have successfully registered.")
    window.location = ('loginPage')
</script>
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal error 'yes' %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Something went wrong.")
</script>
{% endifequal %}
{% endblock %}
```